# Div doesn't start after the previous div, it gets hidden behind

Tags: css, positioning

http://mehulkar.com/CD

This is driving me insane. I have a fixed position header and a fixed position footer. I want the page class to scroll between the two.

For some reason, my page class starts at top:0 of the entire document, instead of starting below the header.

I could bypass the problem by relative positioning all contents of the div by the appropriate height, but I will be using page IDs to navigate the page. So when I navigate to an #ID using an a link, it navigates to the top of the document.

How do I fix this!?

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin to the top of the content to the same height as the div header?  That may work.  Another option would be to have 3 divs (header, content, footer) and then have overflow set to auto on the content div to allow scrolling of the content.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header position is `fixed`, which takes it out of the flow of the document. Not only does that mean it sits where you put it, but it also means it doesn't push the content below it downwards.

Easy fix would be to add a margin to the page div that's exactly the size of the "always-on-top" header.

Comment: i knew there was an easy fix. yes, margin-top is the easiest fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your css class "cleared" seems to have a height of 0. make sure the min-height is set to 100px

Answer (score 0):

To start with try changing your **page** class property:

`margin:0` to `margin-top: 100px`

To move the footer to the left, if that is what you want remove:

`right: 0` from your `#footer` css.

Also remove `position:absolute` from #content css and add `margin-left:200px;`

And add `margin-bottom:50px` to the .wrap class in css.

Once all these changes have been made you should have your header at the top, footer at the bottom, both left aligned. And the content of the page readable and scrollable between the header and footer, with it all being visible with scrolling.

Any questions just ask.

Comment: awesome. is there a reason you prefer adding a left margin to absolute positioning with right:0; ?

Comment: Also, the footer is on the right by design. Not sure if I love it there, but I meant it to be there.